# User definded not set to Inherited label control

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have created a class in c#.net named MyLabel which has base Label(Windows Label control class) class. I have added an user defined Property i.e

```
Format { get; set; }
```

On the win form when I placed the object of MyLabel; I am getting Format property in PropertyGrid control and I can change it but when on execution I didn't get the set value infact getting default value always.

Comment: where/how do you set the value?

Comment: is this wpf? If so, you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call it in the setter

Comment: What is Format? And where does it do anything?

Comment: I am setting the value from propertygrid. It is not in wpf. It is property name of string datatype.

Comment: yes but where is its functionality implemented? here its just an automatic property,where is it used?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to format the Label's text by a property.

Well, you will need to do a little more; the word *Format* alone will not do..

Here is one way: It involves to do the Painting of the Label yourself, which is instructive but also a lot of work..

```
public partial class MyLabel : Label
{

  public MyLabel ()
  {
    //..
    Paint += MyLabel _Paint;
    Format = "{0}";
  }

  public string Format { get; set; }

  void MyLabel _Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     using (SolidBrush fBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor) )
     using (SolidBrush bBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor) )
     { 
        if (Format == "") Format = "{0}";
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bBrush, this.ClientRectangle);
        string fs = string.Format(Format, Text);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(fs, this.Font, fBrush, new Point(Margin.Left, Margin.Top));
     }
  }
}
```

Note that this is really just a rather simple implementation. Depending how compatible you want the Label to behave, you may want to also implement the functionality of the TextAlign, AutoSize and many other properties of Label..

Maybe you'd rather create a Text-assignment function to assign the Text already formatted?

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    if (Format == "") Format = "{0}";
    Text = string.Format(Format, text);
}
```

Comment: No. Here no inheritance used. Actually, when I am placing my custom control and trying to change the property from propertygrid I am not getting that value. Infact, in propertygrid it is showing new value.

Comment: What do you mean _no inheritance used_?? Your title says _Inherited label_ and if you can add a Property you must have inherited it. Or did you add the Property to the Window? Show us a bit more of the __real__ code! What you've shown would not even compile!

Comment: public class DataFormatField : Label {
   [Browsable(false)]
   public override string Text { get; set; }

   private string _format = "&p";
   [Browsable(true)]
   public string Format {
      get { return this._format; }
      set {
          if (value != this._format) {
            this._format = value;
         }
     }
   }
}

This is the code.

Comment: @Kamlesh in your code the format property will ofcourse show in the properties window but there is no place where your CUSTOM PROPERTY is used to alter something at all.Its the same as if you created an event placed the method where it would call the list of listeners but you didnt raise the event anywhere...

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do nor what your problem is. Please clarify! If I add this to a button click: `button1.Text = dataFormatField1.Format;`the format set in the property grid shows just fine.. What do you want to achieve by overriding Text??